# questions about filter function in python

Tags: python

```
def empty(s):
    return s and s.strip()
print(list(filter(empty,['A','B',' C '])))
```

Operation results ：['A', 'B', ' C ']
I was so confused about " C "
In my opinion: s.strip() cause to delete space of the " C " and return "C",function will be returned false,and filter will eliminate it.
so the result should be ['A','B'] ?

my English is not well,I'm tring to tell confusion clear.

Comment: `filter` decides whether to keep values or not, it doesn’t *alter* the values.

Comment: *”delete space of the " C " and return "C",function will be returned false”* — Why? `"C"` is a truthy value.

Comment: thanks for all. I have understanded for it

Answer (score 0):

Switch to '==' instead of 'and' because currently you just check if both s and its trimmed version are non empty:

```
def empty(s):
    return s == s.strip()
```

Output: ['A', 'B']